# Getting an unknown "label" from an object

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object

I'm trying to get a "label" (there is probably another name) from an object but don't know how to access it the right way.

More specific: I'm fetching data from a JSON which has an ID field with a value of e.g. "1".
I am trying to get the label "ID" not the value "1", but I don't have any clue how.

EDIT:
["ID": "0",
"BloodType": "AB"
},
{
"ID": "1",
"BloodType": "A"
}],

That's my JSON and i want  to get the key "BloodType". But it could also be called "Disease".

Comment: You want to access the Object key which might be a string. If that so then you can do it like so `jsonObj[myKey]`

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation I'm guessing you want to get the `key` from the requested array.

You could achieve that like shown below:

```
const Example = ({ yourArray }) =>
   Object.entries(yourArray).map(([key, value]) => (
      {key}: {value}
   ));
```

Where `key` is your 'label' you wish to get and `value` is the value of the corresponding array item.
You would want to change the `yourArray` constant to your array.

*[React list and keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)*

Comment: "ID": "0",
      "BloodType": "AB"
    },
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "BloodType": "A"
    },
thats my json. And i want to get the key "BloodType" without knowing that its called "BloodType". So using map that way does'nt work,